# How to replace br tags with &#10; tags in XSL template?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, replace, linefeed

Let's assume I have a simple XML file:

```
<data>
  <text>Hello world!&lt;br&gt;Nice to see you all!&lt;br&gt;Goodbye!</text>
</data>
```

Now I want to replace all `&lt;br&gt;` strings with `&#10;` strings so the result should be e.g.:

```
<transformed>
  <text>Hello world!&#10;Nice to see you all!&#10;Goodbye!</text>
</transformed>
```

How do I do this?

XSL replace functionality is easy to implement (e.g. in http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx) but the tricky part is to get the XSL transformer to output those `&#10;` strings.. I either get invisible normal linefeed or `&amp;#10;`

Perfect answer would be an XSL template which does the trick.

Comment: `&#10;` is an entity reference for the linefeed character and is equivalent. Why do you need it to serialize using an entity reference? For XML parsers both ways are evaluated the same and it should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/data">
    <transformed>
      <text>
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace">&lt;br&gt;</xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="by">&amp;#10;</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </text>
    </transformed>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $replace)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$by" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
<transformed>
  <text>Hello world!&#10;Nice to see you all!&#10;Goodbye!</text>
</transformed>
```

### NB!:

Set [`disable-output-escaping`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping) attribute to `yes`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and complete answer! That XSL file indeed does the trick!